# Store 200mb file in db2 database

Tags: java, db2

I need to pick a file from a remote server of size `200mb` and store it in `db2` database (column as `Blob` type and corresponding Java type as `byte[]`).

Can anyone tell me what will be the good approach for this and how to go with that in Java?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

I amaze that why you want such a big file database. It dramatically reduce your database performance. 
Although to do this use Binary / blob type data to store such a big file.

use these links for more details

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0303stolze/0303stolze.html

http://www.dbforums.com/db2/1663961-insert-data-fields-clob-blob.html

*Try it in some sandbox / virtual location.*

**BEWARE FOR DATA DAMAGE IN BIG FILE TRANSACTION OVER SLOW CONNECTION.**

Comment: Hi, I know its not a good practice to store such a big file in database but its a client requirement. Is there any API in java which takes cares of these thing. I used hibernate to upload 100mb size of file and took so much time and with 200mb i got the error that database log is full.

Comment: Hi, 

Is there any API or something which insert the data in chunks in db2 ?? I know inserting big size blob can cause performance issue but here i just need to get the value from the web service from remote application and insert in my database. 

Thanks...